# Phase change first then raising temperature, is it possible?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, phase-transition

We have a liquid at $X^{\circ}$ Celsius , we want to convert it to $Y^{\circ}$ Celsius gas

1: $X^{\circ}$ Celsius **liquid** absorb latent heat of vaporisation, turn into $X^{\circ}$ Celsius **gas**, and then absorb specific heat capacity to turn into $Y^{\circ}$ Celsius **gas**

2: $X^{\circ}$ Celsius **liquid** absorb specific heat capacity turn into $Y^{\circ}$ Celsius **liquid**, and then absorb latent heat of vaporisation to turn into $Y^{\circ}$ Celsius **gas**

Are the amount of heat required for process 1 and 2 same? Or is there misconception about latent heat? I think that for a substance to change its state, we need to raise its temperature to its boiling/melting point first, then we absorb latent heat of vaporisation and fusion.

Comment: Are both conditions at the same pressure?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot instruct a material to absorb heat by changing phase instead of changing its temperature. When you add heat to a material, the reponse of the material is determined by the material's structure, which is typically mapped on a diagram in (pressure, temperature) space.

You have some ability to *change* the boiling point of a liquid by changing the ambient pressure. For example, you can boil water at room temperature in a vacuum. Boiling is a heat-removing process, so your room-temperature, low-pressure water will stop boiling when either (a) the pressure of the released vapor brings the total pressure above the vapor pressure of the water, (b) the boiling process has removed enough heat that the water is too cold to boil at the ambient pressure, or (c) both.  If you just keep pumping on the vapor above the water, it will boil until it has cooled to its triple point, then convert to a solid-gas mixture as the pressure continues to fall.

We account for this work by tabulating the "enthalpy" of vaporization for a material, rather than the "heat" of vaporization. The enthalpy accounts for the pressure$\times$volume work that must be done by the boiling liquid to push the air out of the way and make room for the new vapor.

The internal energy of a given material at a given temperature is a "state variable": it depends only on the current state variables, like temperature and pressure, and not on his that state was reached. You must always provide the difference between the initial and final energies to effect the state change. But you can build a process that requires more energy than this minimum by introducing some irreversible middle steps — for example, by pumping on your system in a vacuum chamber, or by doing some kind of magic phase-change dance in your laboratory so that the gods of phase changes will smile upon your experiment.

Answer (score 1):

The starting liquid has a known enthalpy at given starting conditions (e.g., temperature and pressure).  The ending vapor also has a known enthalpy at given ending conditions.  The heat that must be added to change the starting liquid into the ending vapor can be obtained by subtracting the starting enthalpy from the ending enthalpy, and due to conservation of energy considerations, the result is path independent.  This means that you need to add the same amount of heat to the starting liquid in both situations, if the starting and ending temperatures and pressures are the same for both situations.

Comment: It strikes me that 1. and 2. are inconsistent. In 1. it appears the boiling point of the liquid is X whereas in 2. the boiling point is Y. What am I missing?

Comment: Differences in the latent heat of vaporization at different temperatures are balanced by different required amounts of liquid pressurization (different amounts of work) to achieve those different boiling temperatures. This work is never completely recoverable upon subsequent expansion because gases are more compliant than liquids. The heat–work sum ends up identical for any path taken between the beginning and end states.

Answer (score 0):

> Are the amount of heat required for process 1 and 2 same? Or is there
> misconception about latent heat?

Process 1 says the boiling point of the liquid is $T=X$. Process 2 says the boiling point of the same liquid is $T=Y$ where $Y\gt X$.  This suggests process 2 is being carried out a higher pressure than process 1. The two processes are shown in the figures below.

In general, the heat added during vaporization is the dominant component of the overall heat addition compared to the heat added to effect temperature change (via specific heat). This would appear to make the latent heat as a function of temperature the critical factor.

According to the following link the latent heat of vaporization generally decreases as the boiling point increases (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_heat). This would suggest that the heat added in Process 1 may be greater than Process 2. But we also need to consider the fact that the specific heat of a liquid (as in Process 2) is generally greater than the specific heat of the superheated vapor (as in Process 1).

Consider the example of one kilogram of water. Let $X=100^{0}$C and $Y=200^{0}$C. From the saturated water table and other sources for specific heats:

**Process 1:**

Latent heat or vaporization @ 100$^{0}$C= 2257 KJ/kg

Specific heat of superheated steam = 2.1 kJ/kg K

**Total heat added (per kg) = 2257 + (2.1)(100) = 2467 kJ**

**Process 2:**

Latent heat of vaporization @ 200$^{0}$C = 1941 kJ

Average specific heat liquid in range 100-200 $^{0}$C = 3.58 kJ/kg K

**Total heat added (per kg)= 1940 + (3.58)(100)= 2298 kJ**

So for the above example for water, more heat is added in Process 1 than 2. But we need to keep in mind that water has a very high latent heat of vaporization. For liquids other than water heat added in Process 1 may not be greater than Process 2.

*Conclusion: The dominance of the latent heat over specific heat associated with phase and temperature changes, and the relationship between latent heat and boiling point temperature suggests more heat may be added in Process 1 than 2.
However, differences in values for specific fluids and the relationship between the specific heat of a given liquid vs , coupled with the temperature range involved, need to be considered before reaching a conclusion for a specific liquid.*

Hope this helps.

[image]